# In-App Purchase initial SKProductsRequest failing.

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct

**The objective**:
I want to test that I can at least validate the IAP's *existence* before continuing on implementation. That is, I don't want to implement *all* of the IAP functionality before I test *any* of it.

**The symptom**:
I am submitting an `SKProductsRequest`. The callback is coming through correctly to the delegate. The `response.products` member is an empty array, and the `response.invalidProductIdentifiers` member has the same IAP IDs that I submitted with the `SKProductsRequest` in the first place.

I double-checked the ID spellings. See below for all the steps I have taken. I include these merely to forestall the well-intentioned advice like "Did you forget to do so-and-so?"

**The question**:
Do I or do I not need to have the app reviewed (Beta review or full-on) to allow this call to succeed? Online opinions differ — pro, con, and ambiguous. To wit:

• **Upload not needed**:
Ray Wenderlich's tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) specifically says the SKProductsRequest should succeed *without* any upload or review of app.

• **Upload needed**:
Another stackoverflow quesion ([In-app purchase 'SKProductsRequest' failing to produce a successful response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279614/in-app-purchase-skproductsrequest-failing-to-produce-a-successful-response)) says that the app must be *"submitted"*. It does not say *submitted for review* (as opposed to merely uploaded for TestFlight) but it implies this. This answer is flagged as correct but I am not sure I believe it.

It seems wrong that I need to have the app reviewed before I test even the first step of the IAP process. Or can I submit an incomplete implementation of IAP? That sounds wrong too.

• **Ambiguous info from Apple**:
The wording of the info box in the iTunesConnect IAP section removes rather than sheds light:

> Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version.
>   Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.

I assume "it" means the IAP. (Bad use of indef. pronoun.) My IAPs are listed in the IAP section, with yellow "Ready to submit" annotations. When I select (click on the left-hand name of the IAP which is also a link) I get to the IAP's particular page. There is no button labeled "Submit" exactly, but there is one labeled "Submit for Review". It is disabled.

The following paragraph in the info box does seem to imply that an app version/IAP combination needs to be reviewed.

> Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has
>   been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be
>   submitted using the table below.

Note that it says the app need only be *uploaded* but the IAP needs to be *submitted for review". Significant? But surely app review *per se* is not a requirement for merely submitting an `SKProductsRequest` to verify the existence of the IAP. Otherwise it would seem that I have to implement *all* of the IAP functionality before I test any of it.

**Addendum — The steps**:

- Created the AppID with IAP enabled. Verified this at Dev Portal.
- Am using Xcode's "Automatically manage sisgning" option for PP generation.
  Xcode generated a Distribution PP but not a Dev PP. (I think that's OK.)
- Verified at Dev Portal that this PP has IAP in "Enabled Services".
- But... how do I *know* that this is the PP being used for signing?
  Using the new Xcode-managed service, the PP setting is "Automatic".
- Created the IAP at iTunesConnect.
- Verified that the IAP's ID is the app bundle ID dot-suffixed by a product-unique string.
- Verified that I am submitting the IAP's product ID without typos.
- Waited a day after creating the IAP.
- Checked the Cleared for Sale checkbox. (It "checked itself" some time after I created the IAPs.)
- Added a sandbox tester.
- Uploaded a new version of the app. (Not for review, just for testing.)
- Launched the app in both Simulator and device, with the failure specified at top of this post.